# What is the difference between these Java Exceptions?

Tags: java

I have two different exceptions, one is named "e" and the other "e1". What I do not understand is: 
**What is the difference between "e" and "e1"?**

Example 1:

```
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e); 
...
```

Example 2:

```
catch (Exception e1) {
        label.setText("SQL Error");
        System.err.println(e1);
...
```

Comment: it's just an identifier, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: They're variable names.  One is named `e`, the other is named `e1`.  You can name your variables whatever you like.

Comment: You could call them `toothpaste` and `energyDrink` if you really wanted.

Comment: If you are asking about the `|` used in example 1, then that is a multi-catch, a feature added in Java 7. See: "[Catching Multiple Exception Types and Rethrowing Exceptions with Improved Type Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)" or "[The Java™ Tutorials - The catch Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)".

Comment: I don't think he's asking about variable names, but rather the differences in syntax.

Comment: @John Ubar, Java docs are well written and eaisly available, try referring to them for relevance and usuage of any class defined by JDK. Once you refer them, try out examples yourself if you still are unclear about some concept or if you get stuck for which you are not able to search any help from the already answered questions on Stack overflow, material available on internet then only ask here a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names themselves do not have any relevance.
But you can not have 2 variables with the same name in  the same try-catch block.
In the first case 'e' is can be of type ClassNotFoundException or SQLException, 
Depending on what exception was thrown.

Comment: these kind of questions shouldn't really be answered.

Comment: These type of comments neither ;)

Comment: Now I know. thank you  all for the quick response, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case:

```
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
   System.out.println(e);
```

Only exceptions of `ClassNotFoundException` or `SQLException` (or their subclasses) will be caught.

In the second case:

```
catch (Exception e1) {
    label.setText("SQL Error");
    System.err.println(e1);
```

Any `Exception` (or subclass of) will be caught.